# Chrome not reachable inside docker network

Tags: google-chrome, docker, nginx, protractor, gitlab-ci

I have a web app which I am trying to test under Gitlab-CI using Protractor.

I am using docker-in-docker in Gitlab-CI to build and test the application.

I have all my services containerized in Docker (a Nginx server to host static files, a Nodejs API, a Postgresql DB and a Nginx reverse proxy, "pointing" to the static files nginx server and the nodejs API).

Yesterday, when running the Protractor tests everything was ok.
Then, I have merged my git branch with another to add new tests.
In the middle of the merge process, I lost my reverse nginx proxy configuration (I've deleted it by mistake), which I had to remade. I do not think that the new reverse-proxy configuration is the problem, but at the same time, this is the only thing that has changed.
Every test is failing now with the error:

```
WebDriverError: chrome not reachable
e2e_1_511616c9d3bd  |       (Session info: headless chrome=68.0.3440.106)
e2e_1_511616c9d3bd  |       (Driver info: chromedriver=2.38 (05121428cd0fc129e40a3694cf5405698236ad14),platform=Linux 4.14.48-coreos-r2 x86_64)
e2e_1_511616c9d3bd  |         at Object.checkLegacyResponse (/usr/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/error.js:546:15)
e2e_1_511616c9d3bd  |         at parseHttpResponse (/usr/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js:509:13)
e2e_1_511616c9d3bd  |         at doSend.then.response (/usr/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js:441:30)
e2e_1_511616c9d3bd  |         at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
e2e_1_511616c9d3bd  |     From: Task: Protractor.get(https://reverseproxy.xyz/) - get url
...
```

I can see in my gitlab-ci console that when the tests start the browser makes some successful requests to the nodejs API.

My nginx reverse proxy configuration:

```
worker_processes  auto;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {

    upstream docker-web {
        server web:4200;
    }

    upstream docker-api {
        server api:8443;
    }

    proxy_redirect      off;
    proxy_set_header    Host        $host;
    proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP   $remote_addr;
    proxy_ssl_session_reuse off;

    server {

        server_name localhost;

        location / {
            proxy_pass https://docker-web;
        }

        location /api/ {
            proxy_pass https://docker-api/;
        }
        listen 443 ssl;
        listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on;
        ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/proxy.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/proxy.key;
        ssl_session_cache shared:le_nginx_SSL:1m;
        ssl_session_timeout 1440m;

        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

        ssl_ciphers "ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA:DES-CBC3-SHA:!DSS";
    }
}
```

My tests are running under an alpine container, with the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM alpine:latest

RUN sed -i -e 's/v[[:digit:]]\.[[:digit:]]/edge/g' /etc/apk/repositories
RUN apk upgrade --update-cache --available

RUN apk add npm
RUN npm install -g protractor

# chromium dependencies
RUN apk add openjdk8-jre-base
RUN apk add nss
RUN apk add chromium
RUN apk add chromium-chromedriver
RUN apk upgrade --no-cache --available
ENV CHROME_BIN /usr/bin/chromium-browser

RUN mkdir /e2e
COPY . /e2e
CMD protractor /e2e/ci-conf.js
```

This is my ci-conf.js

```
exports.config = {
  framework: 'jasmine',
  chromeOnly: true,
  directConnect: true,
  specs: ['src/e2e-spec.js'],
  chromeDriver: '/usr/bin/chrome',
  baseUrl: 'https://reverseproxy.xyz', // reverseproxy.xyz is the name of my reverse proxy docker-compose service
  capabilities: {
    browserName: 'chrome',
    acceptInsecureCerts: true, // I'm currently using self-signed certificates in the reverse-proxy
    chromeOptions: {
      args: ['headless','no-sandbox', 'disable-gpu', '--window-size=1920,1080']
    }
  }
}
```

My docker-compose, which I use to initialize the app and start the tests:

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  reverseproxy.xyz:
    image: registry.gitlab.com/projectname/reverseproxy:latest
    depends_on:
      - web
    ports:
      - 443:443
  web:
    image: registry.gitlab.com/projectname/web:42-ci
    depends_on:
      - api
  db:
    image: registry.gitlab.com/projectname/db:42-ci
    volumes:
      - postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data
  api:
    image: registry.gitlab.com/projectname/api:42-ci
    depends_on:
      - db
  e2e:
    image: e2e:latest
    depends_on:
      - reverseproxy.xyz
volumes:
  postgres:
```

My gitlab-ci testing stage:

```
web_integration_tests:
  stage: test
  script:
    - docker-compose pull
    - docker-compose up -d db
    - docker-compose up -d api
    - docker-compose up -d web
    - docker-compose up -d reverseproxy.xyz
    - sleep 5
    - docker-compose up --exit-code-from
```

An example of a test that I'm trying to run inside e2e-spec.js:

```
describe('Be logged in', function() {
  let showAddAccounts = element(by.id('accountIconList'));
  let fbLoginBtn = element(by.id('fbLoginBtn'));

  beforeEach(function() {
    browser.get('');
  });

  it('Should Login in facebook', function() {
    browser.sleep(500);
    showAddAccounts.click();
    fbLoginBtn.isPresent().then((isPresent) => {
      if (isPresent) { // does not appear if already logged in
        fbLoginBtn.click().then( () => {
          browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);
          browser.getCurrentUrl().then(url => {
            browser.driver.findElement(by.id('email')).sendKeys(test_email);
            browser.driver.findElement(by.id('pass')).sendKeys(test_pass);
            browser.driver.findElement(by.id('loginbutton')).click();
            browser.waitForAngularEnabled(true);
          });
        })
      }
    });
    expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).toContain(`manage-accounts`);
  });
});
```

This exactly same test was running well 1 day ago.

I have searched this issue a lot, and almost all solutions point to downgrade chrome or chromedriver. But, as my tests were running yesterday with exactly the same versions of chrome and chromedriver, I do not think that this is the issue.

I have also tried to use another docker image, to run the tests, based on node10-stretch with chrome v70.0.3538.67 and chromedriver v2.43.600233, and had the same error.

When I run these tests in my Win10 machine without using docker, all the tests get green.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I think you're passing arguments to your browser incorrectly. In your config try to use this `args: ["--no-sandbox", "--window-size=1920,1080", "--headless", "--disable-gpu"]`

Comment: @SergeyPleshakov, I've already tried that before.

Comment: args: ["--no-sandbox", "--window-size=1920,1080", "--headless", "--disable-gpu"] works for me as well.

Comment: I don't see how this is useful given that your problem stated **Yesterday, when running the Protractor tests everything was ok. Then, I have merged my git branch with another to add new tests.** and your answer is a configuration option on a `/dev/shm` which has nothing to do with angular and could not have been caused by a merge. I have voted to close this question (it should probably be deleted too)

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution.
I had to set the size of the /dev/shm partition to 2 gb in my docker-compose e2e service using the argument shm_size: '2gb'.