# Dockerized Angular E2E tests pass on local machine, but timeout in Travis CI

Tags: angular, selenium, docker, protractor, travis-ci

I attempted to dockerize my angular e2e tests. Simply, I created a docker-compose.test.yml file:

```
version: "3.4"

services:
  # set up angular app
  angular:
    build: 
      context: ./frontend
      dockerfile: sample.Dockerfile
      target: test
    image: angular:test
    container_name: angular
    ports: 
      - "4200:4200"
    depends_on: 
      - nodejs 
    command: npm run e2e -- --protractor-config=e2e/protractor-docker.conf.js --host 0.0.0.0

  nodejs:
    build:
      context: ./backend
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      target: development
    image: nodejs:dev
    container_name: nodejs
    ports: 
      - "3000:3000"
    networks:
      - backend
    depends_on: 
      - db
    restart: always
  # the mongo database
  db:
    image: mongo
    container_name: db
    networks: 
      - backend
    ports: 
      - "27017:27017"
networks: 
  backend: 
    driver: bridge
```

For the protractor configuration, I followed the tutorial found in this link:

[Angular Tutorial for Travis CI](https://angular.io/guide/testing#configure-cli-for-ci-testing-in-chrome)

I had to make some adjustments along, as such:

```
let config = require('./protractor.conf').config;

// Tell protrator where the chrome driver is
// https://gitlab.com/dasch8/angular-ci/
// https://hub.docker.com/r/weboaks/node-karma-protractor-chrome/
config.chromeDriver = "/usr/bin/chromedriver";

config.allScriptsTimeout = 60000;

config.getPageTimeout = 60000;

config.jasmineNodeOpts.defaultTimeoutInterval = 60000;

// have it connect to the angular app
// config.baseUrl = "http://angular:4200";

config.capabilities = {
  browserName: 'chrome',
  chromeOptions: {
    args: ['--headless', '--no-sandbox', '--disable-gpu']
  },

};


exports.config = config;
```

Using the configuration, the e2e tests are successful on my local machine. However, when I run this in the script for .travis.yml:

```
before_script: 
    - docker-compose -f docker-compose.test.yml build
  script:
    - docker-compose -f docker-compose.test.yml run --name angular -p 4200:4200 angular
```

Travis CI fails. The output is:

```
 - Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.
  - Failed: Timed out waiting for asynchronous Angular tasks to finish after 60 seconds. This may be because the current page is not an Angular application. Please see the FAQ for more details: https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/timeouts.md#waiting-for-angular
```

That is very strange because I wrote:

```
import { AppPage } from './app.po';

// Test bed
describe('workspace-project App', () => {
  let page: AppPage;

  beforeEach(() => {
    page = new AppPage();
  });

  it('should display navbar with title',  () => {
    page.navigateTo().then(() => {
      console.log('Successfully connected to the page');
    });

    expect(page.getHeaderText()).toEqual('hobbies');

  });
});
```

And in the logs for Travis CI, the log prints out:

Successfully connected to the page. The rest of the logs are found here:

[My Travis CI logs](https://travis-ci.com/manofthelionarmy/ci_cd_project/jobs/181874930)

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. It's so strange the test passes on my local machine. I tried to solve this in a different way by using selenium/hub and selenium/node-chrome images and made protractor connect to that selenium server. It's the same story. I got it to work on my local machine, but it fails in TravisCI. I'll ask about the selenium problem in another question.

Comment: Do you mean the E2E tests *in the container* are successful on your machine, or if you run them directly? What happens when you use those docker-compose commands locally?

Comment: The E2E tests in the container are successful on my machine. When I ran the docker-compose commands locally, the tests passed. @jonrsharpe

Comment: Hello. I increased all of the timeout vales (config.allScriptsTimeout, config.getPageTimeout, config.jasmineNodeOpts.defaultTimeoutInterval) to 180000 ms. Doing that made my tests pass on Travis CI. However, what if I run in to tests that  take longer? Will I have to guess a proper timeout to ensure that my tests pass in Travis CI?

Comment: I would suggest honing in on where exactly it is failing and adding a dynamic wait before that.  Does it consistently fail at the same point in your tests?

Comment: @C.Peck Yeah it keeps failing in the same point. I was thinking about adding a wait too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally solved it!!! So, I found this link and I drew some inspiration:
[Chrome Not Reachable in Docker Network](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53326458/chrome-not-reachable-inside-docker-network)

Luckily, the configurations the individual was using were nearly the same, but the interesting part was that the individual was reverse proxying to their web application.

I did the same:

```
#default.conf for proxy service

upstream docker-web {

    #docker angular container
    server angular:4200; 
}

upstream docker-node {

    #docker nodejs container
    server nodejs:3000;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://docker-web;
        #proxy_redirect off; 
        proxy_set_header   Host $host;
        proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
        add_header         X-Upstream $upstream_addr;
    }

    location /api {
        proxy_pass http://docker-node;
        proxy_redirect off; 
        proxy_set_header   Host $host;
        proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
        add_header         X-Upstream $upstream_addr;
    }

    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }
}
```

And for my angular web app hosted on nginx:

```
server {
    listen       4200;
    server_name  localhost;

    #charset koi8-r;
    #access_log  /var/log/nginx/host.access.log  main;

    location / {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }



    #error_page  404              /404.html;

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }
}
```

I created a separate container for protractor using my angular image, which I will provide:

```
###################
##    builder    ##
###################

FROM  node:10-alpine AS builder
RUN  mkdir -p /usr/src/frontend
WORKDIR /usr/src/frontend
COPY package.json /usr/src/frontend
RUN npm cache clean --force \
  && npm install
COPY . /usr/src/frontend
RUN npm run build -- --prod


##################
##  production  ##
##################

FROM nginx:alpine AS production
COPY --from=builder /usr/src/frontend/dist/frontend /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY --from=builder /usr/src/frontend/nginx/default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]

#################
## development ##
#################

# because development uses the same stuff from builder image
FROM builder AS development
EXPOSE 4200
CMD ["npm", "start"]


##################
##     test     ##
##################


# because test uses the same stuff from builder image
FROM builder AS test
RUN apk update && \
    apk upgrade && \
    apk add --no-cache chromium nss chromium-chromedriver
EXPOSE 9876
ENV CHROME_BIN /usr/bin/chromium-browser
# just needed the chromedriver!!!
# https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/5019
# https://gitlab.com/dasch8/angular-ci/blob/master/README.md
CMD [ "npm", "run", "test", "--", "--no-watch", "--no-progress", "--browsers=ChromeHeadlessCI"]


FROM production
```

I then created a selenium grid service and chrome-node service too. The documentation for Docker Selenium is found here:

[Docker Selenium](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium)

My error was that the hostnames (container/ service names in docker-compose file) weren't resolving correctly because they weren't on the same network. Since protractor connects to selenium, and selenium handles the E2E tests, `browser.get('http://proxy')` couldn't find the angular app because Selenium wasn't on the same network as the proxy container. I then removed all the networks I used in my docker-compose file and made a new docker-compose file that includes my selenium grid service (called selenium-hub), selenium/node-chrome service (called chrome_node), MEAN stack (angular, nodejs, db), and protractor service (by targeting the test build from the docker file).

My docker-compose.selenium.yml file:

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  selenium-hub:
    image: selenium/hub:3.141.59
    container_name: selenium-hub
    environment: 
      - GRID_TIMEOUT=10000
    ports: 
      - "4444:4444"
    privileged: true
    #tty: true

  chrome_node:
    image: selenium/node-chrome:3.141.59
    volumes: 
      - /dev/shm:/dev/shm
    container_name: chrome_node
    environment:
      - HUB_PORT_4444_TCP_ADDR=selenium-hub
      - HUB_PORT_4444_TCP_PORT=4444
    ports:
      - "5555:5555"
    privileged: true
    depends_on:
      - selenium-hub
    #tty: true
  proxy: 
    build: 
      context: ./proxy
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: proxy
    container_name: proxy
    # HOST:CONTAINER
    ports: 
      - "80:80"
    #tty: true
    depends_on: 
      - angular
  angular:
    build:
      context: ./frontend
      dockerfile: sample.Dockerfile
      target: production
    image: angular:prod
    container_name: angular
    ports:
      - "4200:4200"
    privileged: true 
    depends_on: 
        - nodejs
    #tty: true
  nodejs:
    build:
      context: ./backend
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      target: development
    image: nodejs:dev
    container_name: nodejs
    ports: 
      - "3000:3000"
    depends_on: 
      - db
    restart: always
    #tty: true
  # the mongo database
  db:
    image: mongo
    container_name: db
    ports: 
      - "27017:27017"
    #tty: true
  protractor:
    build:
      context: ./frontend
      dockerfile: sample.Dockerfile
      target: test
    image: angular:test
    container_name: protractor
    ports: 
      - "9876:9876"
    privileged: true
    depends_on:
      - selenium-hub
      - chrome_node
    #tty: true --> not neccesary
    command: npm run e2e -- --protractor-config=e2e/protractor-ci.conf.js --webdriver-update=false --dev-server-target=
```

And here's my new protractor config file:

```
let config = require('./protractor.conf').config;


// do not use the chromeDriver. If you do, it will not connect to Selenium service
config.directConnect = false;


// have it connect to the angular app
config.baseUrl = "http://proxy";

// Protractor getting the page-timeout
config.getPageTimeout = 60000;

// Selenium Webdriver timeout
config.allScriptsTimeout = 60000;

// Jasmine test script timeout
config.jasmineNodeOpts.defaultTimeoutInterval = 60000;

config.seleniumAddress = 'http://selenium-hub:4444/wd/hub'

config.capabilities = {
  browserName: 'chrome',
  chromeOptions: {
    args: ['--headless', '--disable-gpu', '--no-sandbox'],
  },
};
```

The flag `--dev-server-target=` let's angular know to not start up ng serve (because we are starting up our angular app in nginx). After doing so, my tests passed!!! And, I set the timeouts down to 60000 and the tests passed within 3 secs, a big improvement!!!! :)

The script I used in .travis.yml:

```
before_script: 
        - docker-compose -f docker-compose.selenium.yml build
script:
        - docker-compose -f docker-compose.selenium.yml up -d chrome_node proxy
        - docker container ls
        - docker-compose -f docker-compose.selenium.yml up protractor
```

And for the networking, `docker-compose up` command handles that by all itself, and Docker's DNS resolver will resolve the hostnames (our container/service names in the docker-compose file). More about docker compose networks is found in Docker's documentation: [Docker Compose and Networks](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/)

Here's the logs to the build:

[Travis CI logs](https://travis-ci.com/manofthelionarmy/ci_cd_project/jobs/183015536)

I hope this helps anyone in the future :)

Answer (score 1):

I followed the answer by C.Peck. I tested on my local machine, and it worked; however, it still didn't work in TravisCI, as shown in my logs:

[TravisCI logs](https://travis-ci.com/manofthelionarmy/ci_cd_project/jobs/182202345).

I even set the wait timeout to 11 seconds, and the tests still failed. I then increased the `allScriptsTimeout` in `protractor-docker.conf.js` to 180000. After doing so, the tests passed:

[My Travis CI logs of the Successful Angular E2E Test](https://travis-ci.com/manofthelionarmy/ci_cd_project/jobs/182207675)

However, the test took 2 minutes and 10 seconds to finish. It is frustrating because I was simply checking if the title appears in the navbar. I'm afraid if I test for something such as a form and clicking buttons, Travis CI may even take longer.

Comment: As I feared, the tests timeout when I was trying to test my form. It worked on my local machine, but timeout on Travis CI

Comment: This should not be necessary, that is an absurdly long time have to consistently wait.  I wish I could tell you what's going on but there's clearly a problem here.

Comment: I exactly feel the same way, and these tests are nearly making me rip my hair out.  @C.Peck

Comment: I think I found the possible culprit. In environment.ts, it contains the url for the NodeJs backend. However, that url contains the IP address for my docker-machine on my local machine. That IP address is not the same as the one in TravisCI. I tried replacing it with: `http://nodejs:3000` because my nodejs service from docker-compose is named `nodejs`.

Comment: If that is the case, I’m curious why extending the timeout value made the tests pass?

Comment: The tests passed before when I was just checking if a header component contained the header text. I added some new tests that involve filling out a form, and on submit, it makes a post request request. On ngOnInit(), I have it making get requests to the node server, but I figured out it's getting an ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED in Travis CI

Comment: The issue I'm now facing is that dns names can't be resolved in the browser. They can only be resolved in the docker container in the same docker network. Therefore, making http requests from angular to `http://localhost:3000` and `http://nodjes:3000` won't work. Which means, to make it pass I have to get the docker host IP in Travis CI, which I'm afraid won't be a constant IP.

Comment: I have an idea for a workaround. I have a production image for my angular app. It's static html files are served on nginx. The dns for the nodejs server is revsolved when I use nginx's reverse proxy. Therefore, I have to run the production image, then I have to run the protractor script separately.

Comment: Which may also explain why my tests were stalling out. When waitForAngularEnable(true), it will wait until http calls are finished. Since in onNgOnit I'm making get requests, it will result in ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED, thus making the tests stall out.

Comment: @C.Peck I solved it!!! And I want to take the time to say thank you for taking your time for trying to help me. I appreciate it :)

Comment: Nice work! Absolutely hate those problems that you can’t produce locally, glad you were able to solve it.

Comment: Also, why don’t you put the details of the solution in your answer so that it can easier help anyone else who might hit this issue

Comment: @C.Peck Gotchu :)

Answer (score 0):

So, does adding a wait as follows affect anything?

```
import { AppPage } from './app.po';

// Test bed
describe('workspace-project App', () => {
  let page: AppPage;

  beforeEach(() => {
    page = new AppPage();
  });

  it('should display navbar with title',  () => {
    page.navigateTo().then(() => {
      console.log('Successfully connected to the page');
    });

browser.ignoreSynchronization = true

driver.wait(function () {
return driver.isElementPresent(page.getHeaderText('hobbies'));
}, timeout);

    expect(page.getHeaderText()).toEqual('hobbies');

    browser.ignoreSynchronization = false;

  });
});
```

Comment: I did as you suggested, and I still got a timeout error. https://travis-ci.com/manofthelionarmy/ci_cd_project/jobs/182202345 

Here's my github repo for the code I added as you suggested: https://github.com/manofthelionarmy/ci_cd_project/blob/fixing_protractor/frontend/e2e/src/app.e2e-spec.ts 

@C.Peck

Comment: I'd try one more thing: turn off `waitforAngular()` before the action and tell it to turn back on afterwards, notice the 

`browser.ignoreSychronization` lines.  Any different outcome?

Comment: I've cloned your project but have a lot of setup to do to get it going, working on it though.

Comment: I'd suggest to remove the encryption lines in my .travis.yml. Travis will stop because I encrypted some files by using travis @C.Peck

Comment: I'm stuck with the following error right now and I believe I have everything installed:

`Error: TSError: ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript:
error TS2688: Cannot find type definition file for 'jasmine'.
error TS2688: Cannot find type definition file for 'jasminewd2'.
error TS2688: Cannot find type definition file for 'node'.`

Comment: That makes it look like I don't have Jasmine installed but I 100% do

Comment: Did you run npm install? The angular version I'm using is angular 7, so I'm not sure if angular7 uses downgraded versions. I found this link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46302864/10837566. @C.Peck

Comment: Yeah, I found that same post and tried it but still not working.

Comment: Have you tried running against a standalone server?

Comment: No I haven't. I posted this in a comment below: 

I think I found the possible culprit. In environment.ts, it contains the url for the NodeJs backend. However, that url contains the IP address for my docker-machine on my local machine. That IP address is not the same as the one in TravisCI. I tried replacing it with: `http://nodejs:3000` because my nodejs service from docker-compose is named `nodejs`